# How should we view/interpret Jacob's initiative involving the rolling of the stone from the mouth of the well?

Tags: hebrew-bible, jacob

Genesis 29:7-9 seems to indicate that the shepherds of Haran had the traditional practice/technique of watering the flock of sheep by waiting until all the sheep flock gather together, and then (Genesis 29:3)the shepherds would roll the stone at the well's mouth which would in turn allow the sheep to get water

How should we view/interpret Jacob's initiative involving the rolling of the stone from the mouth of the well?

To me, it seems that Jacob's infatuation( Or "Love at first sight" ) for Rachel made him go out of his way, and go against the aforementioned traditional practice/technique.

Also, would the other shepherds of Haran viewed Jacob's aforementioned initiative as socially awkward/pathetic/strange/weird/offensive? (LOL, Does Jacob come out looking silly/cheesy/corny/pathetic by trying to court Rachel in this manner? )

> Genesis 29:4-12 (NASB)
> 4 Jacob said to them, “My brothers, where are
> you from?” And they said, “We are from Haran.” 5 He said to them, “Do
> you know Laban the son of Nahor?” And they said, “We know him.” 6 And
> he said to them, “Is it well with him?” And they said, “It is well,
> and here is Rachel his daughter coming with the sheep.” **7 He said,
> “Behold, it is still high day; it is not time for the livestock to be
> gathered. Water the sheep, and go, pasture them.” 8 But they said, “We
> cannot, until all the flocks are gathered, and they roll the stone
> from the mouth of the well; then we water the sheep.”**
>
> 9 While he was still speaking with them, Rachel came with her father’s
> sheep, for she was a shepherdess. **10 When Jacob saw Rachel the
> daughter of Laban his mother’s brother, and the sheep of Laban his
> mother’s brother, Jacob went up and rolled the stone from the mouth of
> the well and watered the flock of Laban his mother’s brother.** 11 Then
> Jacob kissed Rachel, and lifted his voice and wept. 12 Jacob told
> Rachel that he was a [c]relative of her father and that he was
> Rebekah’s son, and she ran and told her father.

Comment: Please feel free to give the spiritually and/or symbolic explanation also.  I'll be glad to know it.

Answer (score 4):

This is hermeneutic approach to theatre and drama. This is the scene when the hero and heroine meet for the first time, picturesque and romantic. It should make your heart beat just a little bit faster when you read this passage.

> Genesis 29:1 Then Jacob continued on his journey and came to the land of the eastern peoples.

Jacob, our hero, is different from other people in the area. He is special.

> 2 There he saw a well in the open country, with three flocks of sheep lying near it because the flocks were watered from that well. The stone over the mouth of the well was **large**. 3When all the flocks were gathered there, the **shepherds** would roll the stone away from the well’s mouth and water the sheep. Then **they** would return the stone to its place over the mouth of the well.

The stone is so heavy that it requires the joined effort of the shepherds to move it. The stage is set.

> 4Jacob asked the shepherds, “My brothers, where are you from?”
>
> “We’re from Harran,” they replied.
>
> 5He said to them, “Do you know Laban, Nahor’s grandson?”
>
> “Yes, we know him,” they answered.
>
> 6Then Jacob asked them, “Is he well?”
>
> “Yes, he is,” they said, “and here comes his daughter **Rachel** with the sheep.”

Now, entering Rachel, our heroine, her beautiful form becomes clearer and clearer as she approaches.

> 7“Look,” he said, “the sun is still high; it is not time for the flocks to be gathered. Water the sheep and take them back to pasture.”
>
> 8 “**We can’t**,” they replied, “until all the flocks are gathered and the stone has been rolled away from the mouth of the well. Then we will water the sheep.”

The problem is presented.

> 9 While he was still talking with them, **Rachel** came with her father’s sheep, for she was a shepherd.

Close-up reveals Rachel's beautiful features.

> 10When Jacob saw Rachel daughter of his uncle Laban, and Laban’s sheep, **he** went over and rolled the stone away from the mouth of the well and watered his uncle’s sheep

Problem is solved by Jacob alone. What a man! He Rolls the heavy stone all by himself. To top that off, he even waters Rachel's sheep. The damsel's work is done.

> 11Then Jacob **kissed** Rachel and began to **weep aloud**.

Climax: This superman has a soft side. He is in touch with his feelings.

> 12 He had told Rachel that he was a relative of her father and a son of Rebekah. So she **ran** and told her father.

Love at first sight or what?

The removal of the stone waters more than Rachel's sheep. It opens and waters  the hearts of Jacob and Rachel.